# Algorithm for max number of pairs with two limits

Tags: c++, algorithm

I guess that such an algorithm already exists.

I have two (or more, but two is sufficient for this problem) limits, e.g. limit_a=20 limit_b=18. Then I have some (a, b) pairs, e.g.

(5, 5), (3, 3), (4, 2), (1, 7), (3, 2), (5, 9), (7, 4)

The answer should be 5. An example of a solution: (7, 4), (3, 2), (1, 7), (4, 2), (3, 3)

I need to choose as many pairs as possible such that the sum of all "a" elements is less or equal to limit_a and analogously with "b". I thought that it is 2D Knapsack problem, but it isn't.
My best "solution" is to check all permutations of the list of these pairs and check the sums. It's fine for example, like above one, but of course not with bigger one's. My C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int limit_a = 20;
    int limit_b = 18;
    vector<pair<int, int>> vect;
    vect.push_back(make_pair(5, 5));
    vect.push_back(make_pair(3, 3));
    vect.push_back(make_pair(4, 2));
    vect.push_back(make_pair(1, 7));
    vect.push_back(make_pair(3, 2));
    vect.push_back(make_pair(5, 9));
    vect.push_back(make_pair(7, 4));
    int how_many_max = 0;
    do {
        int copy_a = limit_a;
        int copy_b = limit_b;
        int how_many = 0;
        for ( vector<pair<int,int>>::const_iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); it++){
                copy_a -= it->first;
                copy_b -= it->second;
                if((copy_a < 0) || (copy_b < 0)) {
                    break;
                }
                how_many++;
            }
        if (how_many > how_many_max) how_many_max = how_many;
    } while(next_permutation(vect.begin(), vect.end() ));
    cout << how_many_max;
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
int limit_a = 30;
int limit_b = 80;
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vect = {{37, 20}, {90, 45}, {76, 33}, {3, 93}, {66, 71}, {48, 21}, {8, 28}, {24, 83}, {99, 13}, {42, 52}, {81, 15}, {2, 38}, {7, 19}, {32, 65}, {70, 85}, {12, 82}, {61, 6}, {60, 31}, {46, 34}, {43, 62}, {41, 78}, {64, 80}, {88, 86}, {77, 16}, {44, 100}, {92, 57}, {40, 53}, {9, 56}, {68, 67}, {23, 11}, {35, 30}, {69, 84}, {75, 27}, {87, 26}, {50, 36}, {79, 73}, {4, 91}, {17, 98}, {51, 29}, {25, 95}, {14, 55}, {10, 58}, {54, 49}, {97, 63}, {59, 72}, {1, 39}, {18, 22}, {94, 74}, {96, 5}, {47, 89}
```

Should give `3`: `({2, 38}, {7, 19}, {18, 22})`

Comment: @JeJo duplicates are fine here. limit_a=3, limit_b=3 and pairs: (1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1). The answer in my case is 3 (three 1,1 pairs)

Comment: without changing the algorithm substantially there are some improvments you can do, eg `(3,2)` is definitely in because both are minimal

Comment: @idclev463035818 what do you mean that both are minimal? There is also `(1, 7)` in the example.

Comment: oh sorry, missed that one, then there is none in your input :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a 2D knapsack problem, just the profits are all 1. The usual approach of generating subsets interleaved with pruning where a partial subsolution obviously dominates another applies.

Some quick code below, using sorting instead of a merge for convenience.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int limit_a = 20;
  int limit_b = 18;
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vect = {{5, 5}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {1, 7},
                                           {3, 2}, {5, 9}, {7, 4}};
  limit_a = 30;
  limit_b = 80;
  vect = {{37, 20}, {90, 45}, {76, 33}, {3, 93},   {66, 71}, {48, 21}, {8, 28},
          {24, 83}, {99, 13}, {42, 52}, {81, 15},  {2, 38},  {7, 19},  {32, 65},
          {70, 85}, {12, 82}, {61, 6},  {60, 31},  {46, 34}, {43, 62}, {41, 78},
          {64, 80}, {88, 86}, {77, 16}, {44, 100}, {92, 57}, {40, 53}, {9, 56},
          {68, 67}, {23, 11}, {35, 30}, {69, 84},  {75, 27}, {87, 26}, {50, 36},
          {79, 73}, {4, 91},  {17, 98}, {51, 29},  {25, 95}, {14, 55}, {10, 58},
          {54, 49}, {97, 63}, {59, 72}, {1, 39},   {18, 22}, {94, 74}, {96, 5},
          {47, 89}};
  std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> frontier = {
      {{limit_a, limit_b}}};
  for (auto [a, b] : vect) {
    frontier.push_back({});
    for (std::size_t how_many = frontier.size() - 1; how_many > 0; how_many--) {
      std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &level = frontier[how_many];
      for (auto [residual_a, residual_b] : frontier[how_many - 1]) {
        if (residual_a >= a && residual_b >= b)
          level.push_back({residual_a - a, residual_b - b});
      }
      if (level.empty())
        continue;
      std::sort(level.begin(), level.end(),
                std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>());
      auto output = level.begin();
      auto input = output;
      for (++input; input != level.end(); ++input) {
        if (std::tie(input->second, input->first) >
            std::tie(output->second, output->first))
          *++output = *input;
      }
      level.erase(++output, level.end());
      if ((false)) {
        for (auto [residual_a, residual_b] : level) {
          std::cout << residual_a << ',' << residual_b << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
      }
    }
  }
  std::size_t how_many_max = frontier.size() - 1;
  while (frontier[how_many_max].empty())
    how_many_max--;
  std::cout << how_many_max << '\n';
}
```

In higher dimensions, the pruning gets more complicated. The curse of dimensionality also kicks in because domination relation gets sparser. Integer programming might be a better solution here.

Comment: I checked your code and something is wrong. I added an additional example to my post.

Comment: Yes, now all results seem to be correct. Thank you. I think you forgot `#include <tuple>` on the beginning (error `tie is not a member of std` occurs without it)

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz Ah yes, usually I write C++ at work, where I have IWYU set up to fix this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

A naive search space for bottom-up dynamic programming seems to be `O(n * limit_a * limit_b)` but this can get a lot more idiosyncratic, depending on the input, so we could possibly favour a memoised recursion.

```js
function f(pairs, a, b, i=0, memo={}){
  if (i == pairs.length)
    return 0;
  
  const key = String([i, a, b]);
  if (memo.hasOwnProperty(key))
    return memo[key];
    
  // Skip this pair
  let best = f(pairs, a, b, i+1, memo);
  
  const [l, r] = pairs[i];
  
  // Maybe include this pair
  if (l <= a && r <= b)
    best = Math.max(best, 1 + f(pairs, a-l, b-r, i+1, memo));
    
  return memo[key] = best;
}

var pairs = [
 [5, 5], [3, 3], [4, 2],
 [1, 7], [3, 2], [5, 9], [7, 4]
];

console.log(f(pairs, 20, 18));
```

Comment: I do not know JS (only C++ and Python) but it seems to be working. I'll check it out.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz cool. David Eisenstat's answer is probably more canonical, and I suspect more efficient in the general case due to the pruning.